# Javascript JSON.stringify change my string that contains backslash

Tags: javascript, json

I have this string variable

```
iteration  = "Toolset\\Iteration 1"
```

But when I add the string to a `JSON.stringify` it changes the value adding two more backslashes `Toolset\\\\Iteration 1`

```js
var data = JSON.stringify([
    {
      "op": "add",
      "path": "/fields/System.IterationPath",
      "value": iteration
    }
]);
//output: Toolset\\\\Iteration 1
```

I need the output to be `Toolset\\Iteration 1`

What is the best way of adding that particular string with 2 backslashes to a JSON variable?

Comment: The result you get is `Toolset\\\\Iteration 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON stringify encodes the object into a string. The actual value of the JSON is seen after you decode it from the string. The fact that the stringified version has escaped your slashes won't affect the actual value after the decode.